# Tailwind css table with fixed header and scrolling tbody vertically

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I have the code below for a table based on tailwind css.

If I remove the `block` class, the table is not scrollable anymore.

Adding the `block` class to `tbody` breaks the `thead`. See Images attached.

CodePen if you want to play with the code. https://codepen.io/hirani89/pen/wvyJKqO?editors=1010

```
<div class="address">
  <h1 class="font-medium leading-tight text-3xl mt-0 mb-2">Recipient</h1>
  <div class="item mb-2 md:flex md:flex-wrap md:justify-between">
    <div wire:id="rbWM5jbW8w1GcT2ql3DF" class="container w-full px-4 sm:px-8">
      <div class="my-2 flex sm:flex-row flex-col">
        <div class="block w-1/3 relative">
          <span class="h-full absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-2">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="h-4 w-4 fill-current text-gray-500">
              <path d="M10 4a6 6 0 100 12 6 6 0 000-12zm-8 6a8 8 0 1114.32 4.906l5.387 5.387a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-5.387-5.387A8 8 0 012 10z">
              </path>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <input autocomplete="off" wire:model.debounce.500ms="query" placeholder="Search" class="appearance-none rounded-r rounded-l border border-gray-400 border-b block pl-8 pr-6 py-2 w-full bg-white text-sm placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:placeholder-gray-600 focus:text-gray-700 focus:outline-none">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col">
        <div class="overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
          <div class="py-2 inline-block w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="overflow-hidden">
              <table class="w-full">
                <thead class="bg-white border-b">
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="text-md font-medium text-gray-900 px-6 py-4 text-left">
                      Select
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" class="text-md font-medium text-gray-900 px-6 py-4 text-left">
                      Company
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" class="text-md font-medium text-gray-900 px-6 py-4 text-left">
                      Address
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="h-96 block overflow-y-auto">
                  <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="1">
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                      BATHURST </td>
                    <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="2">
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                      BATHURST
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                      MUDGEE
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="4">
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                      ORANGE
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="5">
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                      TAREN POINT
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without `block` class in `tbody` (disables scroll)
[image]

With `block` class in `tbody` (scroll works but header breaks)

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could add a `max-height` to your table's parent div and
set `position:sticky` and `top:0` for your `thead`

```
<div class="table-wrp block max-h-96">
  <table class="w-full">
    <thead class="bg-white border-b sticky top-0">
      <!-- table head content -->
    </thead>
    <tbody class="h-96 overflow-y-auto">
      <!-- table body content -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

#### Example

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">

  <main>
    <div class="py-12">
      <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg py-4 px-4">
          <form class="mb-4" method="POST" action="https://shipping.local/login">

            <div class="address">

              <div class="item mb-2 md:flex md:flex-wrap md:justify-between">
                <div wire:id="rbWM5jbW8w1GcT2ql3DF" class="container w-full px-4 sm:px-8">

                  <div class="flex flex-col">
                    <div class="overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
                      <div class="py-2 inline-block w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8">

                        <div class="table-wrp block max-h-96">
                          <table class="w-full">
                            <thead class="bg-white border-b sticky top-0">
                              <tr>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-md font-medium text-gray-900 px-6 py-4 text-left">
                                  Select
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-md font-medium text-gray-900 px-6 py-4 text-left">
                                  Company
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-md font-medium text-gray-900 px-6 py-4 text-left">
                                  Address
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody class="h-96 overflow-y-auto">
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="1">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  BATHURST </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="2">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  BATHURST
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="3">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  MUDGEE
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="4">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  ORANGE
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="5">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  TAREN POINT
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="1">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  BATHURST </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="2">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  BATHURST
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="3">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  MUDGEE
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="4">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  ORANGE
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="5">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  TAREN POINT
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="1">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  BATHURST </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="2">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  BATHURST
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="3">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  MUDGEE
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="4">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  ORANGE
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="bg-white border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="5">
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                  TAREN POINT
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-sm text-gray-900 font-light px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Livewire Component wire-end:rbWM5jbW8w1GcT2ql3DF -->

              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

#### In plain css:

```
.table-wrp  {
  max-height: 75vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display:block;
}
thead{
  position:sticky;
  top:0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution i come up with .

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="container p-4">
  <h1 class="mt-0 mb-2 text-3xl font-medium leading-tight">Recipient</h1>
  <div class="item mb-2 md:flex md:flex-wrap md:justify-between">
    <div wire:id="rbWM5jbW8w1GcT2ql3DF" class="container w-full px-4 sm:px-8">
      <div class="my-2 flex flex-col sm:flex-row">
        <div class="relative block w-1/3">
          <span class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex h-full items-center pl-2">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="h-4 w-4 fill-current text-gray-500">
              <path d="M10 4a6 6 0 100 12 6 6 0 000-12zm-8 6a8 8 0 1114.32 4.906l5.387 5.387a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-5.387-5.387A8 8 0 012 10z"></path>
            </svg>
          </span>
          <input autocomplete="off" wire:model.debounce.500ms="query" placeholder="Search" class="block w-full appearance-none rounded-r rounded-l border border-b border-gray-400 bg-white py-2 pl-8 pr-6 text-sm text-gray-700 placeholder-gray-400 focus:bg-white focus:text-gray-700 focus:placeholder-gray-600 focus:outline-none" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <table class=" border-[1px] border-black text-left">
    <thead class="">
      <tr class="text-left flex justify-items-start">
        <th class="text-md px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 ">Select</th>
        <th class="text-md px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900">Company</th>
        <th class="text-md px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900">Address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- Remove the nasty inline CSS fixed height on production and replace it with a CSS class — this is just for demonstration purposes! -->
    <tbody class="flex flex-col items-center justify-items-start overflow-y-scroll bg-white text-gray-400" style="height: 50vh;">
      <tr class="border-b bg-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="1" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900">BATHURST</td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="border-b bg-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="2" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900">BATHURST</td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="border-b bg-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="3" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900">MUDGEEEE</td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="border-b bg-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="4" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900">ORANGE</td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="border-b bg-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="5" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900">TAREN POINT</td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="border-b bg-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="5" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900">TAREN POINT</td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="border-b bg-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="5" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900">TAREN POINT</td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="border-b bg-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="1" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900">BATHURST</td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="border-b bg-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="2" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900">BATHURST</td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="border-b bg-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="3" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900">MUDGEE</td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="border-b bg-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="4" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900">ORANGE</td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="border-b bg-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="5" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900">TAREN POINT</td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="border-b bg-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="5" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900">TAREN POINT</td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="border-b bg-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100">
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="address" value="5" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-extrabold text-gray-900">TAREN POINT</td>
                    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 text-sm font-light text-gray-900">Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here Address Here</td>
                  </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```